# How do I use multiple methods with user inputs?

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, computer-science, display

I'm pretty new to C# and I have a project coming up. Recently, I've created another dummy project just to get this fact down. I'm just trying to get the user to input their name and for it to be displayed. Here's what I've got so far, which of course is not working. Some help would be greatly appreciated, even if this seems like a very dumb or basic question.

```cs
public class Employee
{
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string GetNames()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
        firstName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey());
        return firstName;
    }

    public Employee()
    {
        firstName = this.firstName;
    }

    public static void Display(string firstName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstName);
    }

}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Console.Write(employee.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey());` <-- `ReadKey` returns after a single keypress, which won't be the user's first-name, unless they have a single-letter first-name, ofc.

Comment: Also, _avoid_ the `Convert` class like the plague. It really needs to be removed from .NET.

Comment: @Dai - rather strong opinion on the Convert class. Any particular reason on it? I’ve personally never had issues with it

Comment: @scottdavidwalker It boxes value-types. All of the non-`Object`-accepting overloads of the `ToIntXXX` methods is better done with a C# cast expression. All of the `Object`-accepting overloads of the `ToIntXX` methods offer no control over exactly how and what conversion is done, often resulting in unexpected results (_especially_ w.r.t. `CultureInfo` and `dd/MM/yyyy` vs `MM/dd/yyyy` (_silly yanks_)). Parsing strings is best done with `IntXX.Try/Parse/Exact`. So there's always a better (and more flexible/configurable) alternative to everything you can do with `Convert`.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker And `Object.ChangeType` does not do what people think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to take you through this step-by-step, starting with a simple implementation of the `Main()` body. This all may be *too* detailed for your needs, but hopefully it provides some helpful insights.

The steps are:

1. Achieving the main goal, the basic way
2. Extracting logic into methods
3. Introducing the `Employee` class
4. Embedding the methods in the `Employee` class

(Note that this is just a *suggested* collection of steps, it is by no means *the only step-by-step* way.)

---

#### 1. Achieving the main goal, the basic way

Let's start with the main goal, which you have stated to be:

> I'm just trying to get the user to input their name and for it to be displayed.

As commented in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160329/how-do-i-use-multiple-methods-with-user-inputs#answer-74160345), `Console.ReadLine()` should be used rather than `Console.ReadKey()` to read a full inputted line (which is terminated by the user pressing Enter).

Seeing as [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0) returns a `string`, there is no need for conversion of the return value to a `string`.

Your main goal (in its simplest form) does *not* include any `Employee` class. It may be achieved by assigning the return value of `Console.ReadLine()` to a variable, and using that variable in the subsequent call to `Console.WriteLine()` to display the first name:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
    var firstName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Your first name is " + firstName);
}
```

When a user runs this and types `Laura`, the console output will be:

> Please enter your first name:
> **> Laura**
> Your first name is Laura

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QVqZ8t).

---

#### 2. Extracting logic into methods

Now, the two first code lines in the `Main()` method are used to request the user for their first name:

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Let's extract that logic into a method.

Seeing as `Main()` is a `static` method, any method called from within `Main()` also needs to be a static method. Hence, we make our method `static` and lets it return what the user inputted after we requested their first name:

```csharp
public static string RequestFirstName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
    var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    
    return firstName;
}
```

With this method in place, our `Main()` body can now be simplified by calling the method:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    var firstName = RequestFirstName();

    Console.WriteLine("Your first name is " + firstName);
}
```

Onto the next part. The last line in `Main()` is used to display the name that the user just provided us with:

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("Your first name is " + firstName);
```

If we want to extract that into a method, we will need to include an input parameter to know which name to actually display; just like you have done in your own implementation. The method does not need to return anything, as its purpose is simply to write to the console. Just like `RequestFirstName()`, this method also needs to be `static`:

```csharp
public static void DisplayFirstName(string firstName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your first name is " + firstName);
}
```

Again, `Main()` can be simplified by calling the newly implemented method:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    var firstName = RequestFirstName();

    DisplayFirstName(firstName);
}
```

Running this code, the console will still display the same as in step 1:

> Please enter your first name:
> **> Laura**
> Your first name is Laura

Example fiddle with the resulting code snippets [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AEpINN).

---

#### 3. Introducing the `Employee` class

I would suggest starting with a very simple implementation of the `Employee` class. Perhaps simply containing one property: `FirstName`.

But first, a side note on your current implementation of `Employee`:
You have implemented a property `FirstName`, which uses a [`backing field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields) for getting and setting its value. (Any `private field` should (according to the [name convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#camel-case)) be prefixed with an underscore, so I will use that in this example.)

Your implementation of `Employee` (when disregarding the constructor and the methods) looks like this:

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    private string _firstName; // Backing field for property

    public string FirstName    // Property
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
}
```

When a property directly gets and sets the value of the backing field, straight-forward, like in this example, *implementing an explicit backing field is not necessary*. As explained in the [Property syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties#property-syntax), all you need is an [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } // Auto-implemented property
}
```

Now, we can create an *`Employee` instance* inside `Main()`, and set its `FirstName` by using the methods we implemented in step 2:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    var employee = new Employee();
    
    employee.FirstName = RequestFirstName();

    DisplayFirstName(employee.FirstName);
}
```

The console will still display the same as previously when running this code:

> Please enter your first name:
> **> Laura**
> Your first name is Laura

Example fiddle with the resulting code snippets [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXEs9n).

---

#### 4. Embedding the methods in the `Employee` class

Finally, it's time to sew it all together. We will embed our request and display methods in `Employee`, so that the methods can be called on the *`Employee` instance* (`employee`) that we have created in `Main()`.

But, we cannot simply copy and paste those methods into the `Employee` class. Or, well, we *could* do it, but if we did, they would not function the way we *want* them to function. For instance, upon requesting a name, the provided name would not be assinged to the `Employee` instance's `FirstName` property.

So we need to make a few changes. First, let's look at the request method from step 2:

1. We want to be able to call the request method on *an `Employee` instance* (`employee`). Any `static` method which is defined inside a class *cannot be called on an instance of that class* from outside the class. Hence, we need to make our methods non-static by removing the `static` keyword. (Read more about the difference between a class and an *instance* of a class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes#creating-objects).)
2. We want to assign the provided name to `FirstName`. Hence, `var firstName` needs to be replaced with `FirstName`.
3. Seeing as `FirstName` will now be set inside the request method, there is no need to actually return that value. We will switch the return type from `string` to `void` and omit the `return` statement.

Our original request method

```csharp
public static string RequestFirstName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
    var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    
    return firstName;
}
```

can hence be embedded in `Employee` as follows:

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public void RequestFirstName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee's first name:");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Similarily, the display method needs some adjustment before embedding it in `Employee`.

Just like the request method, the display method needs to be non-static. In addition, we can remove the input parameter; seeing as the name we want to display is already accessible for us in `Employee`. We will therefore replace `firstName` with the property `FirstName` inside the `Console.WriteLine()` statement.

The original display method

```csharp
public static void DisplayFirstName(string firstName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your first name is " + firstName);
}
```

can hence be embedded in `Employee` as follows:

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public void DisplayFirstName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The employee's first name is " + FirstName);
    }
}
```

After embedding both methods in `Employee`

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public void RequestFirstName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee's first name:");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    public void DisplayFirstName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The employee's first name is " + FirstName);
    }
}
```

, we can call both methods on our *`Employee` instance*, `employee`:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{   
    var employee = new Employee();

    employee.RequestFirstName();
    employee.DisplayFirstName();
}
```

In practice, what we do is:

1. create an *instance* of `Employee` and assign it to `employee`
2. request (and assign) the first name of `employee` by calling the request method on the instance
3. display the first name of `employee` by calling the display method on the instance

The console will display the following:

> Please enter the employee's first name:
> **> Laura**
> The employee's first name is Laura

Example fiddle with the resulting code snippets [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z1g3DB).

Comment: I upvoted this answer without even reading it, simply out of respect for the effort you put in to this, lol. 

Answer (score 0):

Use **Console.ReadLine()**

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Console.ReadKey() only returns one character / key

Comment: Ah thank you, I feel really stupid lol. Still I get the same problem, the output is just black.

Comment: Your program doesn't execute a method GetNames in which you input the Employee name.  And default value for string is null, so Console.Write(employee.FirstName) prints nothing to console. Simpliest way to fix your code is to execute GetNames() before printing

Comment: How would I execute GetNames() before printing?

Comment: `Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.GetNames();
Console.WriteLine(employee.FirstName);`
Now console window will wait for you to enter some name and hit enter button

Comment: So I have another question if you wouldn't mind, how would I get both the method GetNames() and Display() to appear under new Employee()? I tried to put Display() below GetNames(), but I got "there is no argument given that corresponds with the required parameter firstName of Employee.Display(string).

Comment: @ronalddonaldronald, your static method `Display(string firstName)` requires a one argument - some string. You need to pass it like: `Employee.Display("Hello!")`. Or if you want this method to print employee's name, then: 1) Make it **not** `static`. 2) Remove first argument. `Display(string firstName)` --> `Display()`. 3) Execute it on your Employee instance, not on a class: `employee.Display()`, **not** `Employee.Display()`